# How can I save ordered collection in JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, collections, spring-data-jpa

I have an main entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "MAINS")
public class Main {

...

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "main", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = LAZY)
private List<Chield> children;
```

And I have a child entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILDS")
public class Child {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "GUID")
    private String guid;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "Age")
    private Integer age;
```

And I try to save one `Main` with many `Child`:

```
  List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0, i< 10; i++) {
      Child child = new Child();
      child.setId(i);
      child.setName("Name"+i);
      child.setAge(10+i);
      children.add(child);
   }
   main.setChildren(children);
   MainRepository.save(main);
```

But I need to save these children ordered. I can add a new column to `Child` - `order` and set `child.setOrder(order++);` and when I select this list I can sort it by order field.

But can I do it differently? Without adding of the new column?

Comment: How do you want them ordered?

Comment: @ Alan Hay - for example, I save `1 2 3 5 4 6 8`. I need to select `1 2 3 5 4 6 8`. In the order in which added to the list.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question correctly it could be helpful to check such options:

[OrderColumn](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html)

```
   @OrderColumn(name = "index_id")
    private List<Child> changes = new ArrayList<>();
```

OR

```
@OrderBy("id")
private Set<Child>list = new  LinkedHashSet<>();
```

OR

```
@SortNatural
private SortedSet<Child> children = new TreeSet<Child>();
```

DOCS: [naturalSort](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/SortNatural.html)

OR for custom comparator: `@SortComparator(SortById.class)`

DOCS: [customSort](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/SortComparator.html)

```
public class SortById implements Comparator<Child> {

Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SortById.class.getSimpleName());

@Override
public int compare(Child o1, Child o2) {
    log.info("Child.compare");
    return o1.getId().compareTo(o2.getId());
}

}
```

Comment: Do I need add new column for @OrderColumn? I wrote in question, that I seek oution without adding of new column.

Comment: You are right, because it creates new column with order. You could use @OrderBy("id")  because regarding your code you are creating entities and increment the id field. I hope it could be helpful :)

Comment: Please keep in mind that OrderBy is not working as far as I know with List!